# Check if my Nested data exist and display div, else display other div with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to check if my items on `Properties.Properties` or `Implement.Interfaces` exists and display the div with it, if not i want to display a div with information that it doesn't.

*I display the selected div with the select input and it works fine just for info.*

I tried some solution from doucmentation with the `if` anf `ifnot` statements but that didn't work.

An image of my data on the console:
[image]
Here is my **Model**:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myfield =  ko.observableArray([]);
  self.investigator = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.preparatorInfos = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.enumInfos = ko.observableArray([]);



  self.selectDivs = ko.observableArray(['Properties', 'Implements']);
  self.selectedDiv = ko.observable();

  self.selectDivs2 = ko.observableArray(['Properties', 'Requires']);
  self.selectedDiv2 = ko.observable();

}

var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/helloworld');

var vm = new ViewModel();

db.query("bricksetup/docs").then(function(result) { 
  var data = result;
  console.log(data);
  vm.myfield(data.rows);
  //data.rows.forEach(function(row){
      //vm.data.push(row.value)
 // })
   //vm.myfield(data.rows[3].value.Name);
});
db.query("InvestigatorInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
  var data = result;
  console.log(data);
  vm.investigator(data.rows);
});

db.query("PreparatorInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
  var data = result;
  console.log(data);
  vm.preparatorInfos(data.rows);
});

db.query("EnumInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
  var data = result;
  console.log(data);
  vm.enumInfos(data.rows);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And my **index**:

```
<div id="tab1" class="col s12">
            <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" data-bind="foreach:myfield">
                <li  data-bind="with: value">
                  <div class="collapsible-header">
                    <i class="material-icons">view_stream</i>
                    <p class="blue-text" data-bind="text: TypeName"></p>
                  </div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"> 
                      <p class="style_p_row" ><b>AssemblyName:</b> <span data-bind="text: AssemblyName"></span></p>
                      <!-- ko if: Description -->
                       <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Description:</b> <span data-bind="text: Description"></span></p>
                      <!-- /ko -->
                      <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Name: </b><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></p>
                      <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Obsolete: </b><span data-bind="text: Obsolete"></span></p>
                      <p class="style_p_row" ><b>TypeName: </b><span data-bind="text: TypeName"></span></p>
                       <div class="row">
                          <form class="col s12">
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col s12 m12">
                                    <div class="col s12 m4 padding_select">
                                      <select class="browser-default " 
                                      data-bind="options: $root.selectDivs,
                                                value: $root.selectedDiv,
                                                optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
                                      </select>
                                    </div><!-- end col s6 -->
                                    <div class="col s6 m6" >
                                       <div data-bind="visible: $root.selectedDiv() == 'Properties'" id="Properties">
                                       <!-- ko if: Properties.Properties -->
                                        <p class="blue-text padding_p">Properties</p>
                                        <ul data-bind="foreach: Properties.Properties">
                                          <li>
                                          <b>Converter: </b><span data-bind="text: Converter"></span></br>
                                          <b>Name:</b> <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></br>
                                          <b>Validation Type: </b><span data-bind="text: ValidationType"></span></br></br>

                                          </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <!-- /ko -->
                                      </div>
                                      <div data-bind="visible: $root.selectedDiv() == 'Implements'" id="Implements">
                                        <p class="blue-text padding_p">Implements Interfaces</p>
                                        <ul data-bind="foreach: Implements.Interfaces">
                                          <li><b>TypeName:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.TypeName"></span><br></li>
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div><!-- end col s6 -->
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                          </form>
                        </div><!-- end row -->
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: You do not have `Properties`  or `Implements` members in your viewmodel. What are you expecting the `if` bindings based on `Properties.Properties` or `Implements.Interfaces` to see?

Comment: updated the question, addedd the image of my data

Comment: There's a lot of code here that's not directly involved in the question. Is there any way you can distill it down to runnable snippet?
Is the `if: Properties.Properties` section being displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the `if` and check `ifnot` when its null

```
                                   <!-- ko if: Properties.Properties == ''-->
                                     <p class="blue-text padding_p">Properties</p>is nothing set
                                   <!-- /ko -->


                                   <!-- ko ifnot: Properties.Properties == ''-->
                                    <p class="blue-text padding_p">Properties</p>
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach: Properties.Properties">
                                      <li>  
                                      <b>Name:</b> <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></br>        
                                      <b>Converter: </b><span data-bind="text: Converter"></span></br>      
                                      <b>Validation Type: </b><span data-bind="text: ValidationType"></span></br></br>

                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
```

Same goes for **Implements**

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML appears to reference observables which aren't in your view-model.

For example,

```
<p class="style_p_row" ><b>Obsolete: </b><span data-bind="text: Obsolete"></span></p>
<p class="style_p_row" ><b>TypeName: </b><span data-bind="text: TypeName"></span></p>
```

I see neither `Obsolete` nor `TypeName` in your client-side view-model. I *do* see `TypeName` in the data from the server but this isn't the same data which is given to Knockout to render.

So my first suggestion is to 'synchronise' the observables between your view-model and your HTML view.

My second suggestion would be to have properties on your view-model which expose, for example, `hasTypeName`.

```
self.hasTypeName = ko.computed(function() {

    var imps = self.Implements;        

    return imps && imps.Interfaces && imps.Interfaces.TypeName && imps.Interfaces.TypeName.length;

});
```

If you load `TypeName` into an observable then you can change that `return` statement above.

You can then have something like this in your view-model:

```
<!-- ko if: hasTypeName -->
    YOUR HTML
<!-- /ko -->
```